# Open a file in C

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to write a tiny program in C that will open a file and then run the filename in terminal to stream the file to my Apple TV.

The reason I want to do this is so I can right click a media file, select 'Open With', choose 'Apple TV' from the list and then have it stream to my Apple TV via the airstream program.

My code so far is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
   char command[50];

   strcpy( command, "airstream '/home/steve/media.mp4' -o 192.168.0.2" );
   system(command);

   return(0);
}
```

Very simple, but I'm not sure how to handle a file being passed to the application to allow it to get the filename and modify the command.

Comment: you can look here to see how to pass arguments to main: http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter10/arguments_to_main.html But if you need to interact with your window management system (right click openwith) you have to look into its doc to see how to integrate with it

Comment: This is problem that is probably best solved with a shell script

Comment: The answers I see thus far have ignored the fact that your real programming problem is "how do I create a contextual element in the right-click menu of a media file, so that it calls a program I write with the path to the media file as a parameter". I know this is super easy on the MacOS with AppleScript, but I don't know how to do it in Linux. I do know that your question is currently being misinterpreted, so might I suggest that you beef up the wording of the question to get better answers?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/how-do-i-add-context-menu-item-in-gnome-nautilus-557450/ . It looks like this is almost _exactly_ the application you have in mind. You may have to specify what flavor of linux file manager you use if you want a really specific answer.

Comment: I got it working on the menu, buddy... just needed to create a .desktop for it in /usr/share/applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(First, let me make a comment on `strcpy()`: as-is, the call to `strcpy()` is superfluous (and imposes a security issue), because you are using a constant string. You could have written `system("airstream '/home/steve/media.mp4' -o 192.168.0.2")` instead.)

If you want to construct a command given a filename, you **could** in theory write

```
char command[LINE_MAX];
snprintf(command, sizeof command, "some_command %s", argv[1]);
system(command);
```

But that again rises a security problem, because now your program can be hijacked to execute an arbitrary external program, by passing it a malformed command-line argument, similarly to an SQL injection attack.

You'd be better off finding the library/API the `airstream` executable uses, and incorporate that directly into your program. If no such thing exists, you have to make sure to at least validate the user input (i. e. escape special characters, etc.) before handing it over to the shell for execution.

Comment: Worked fine for me, buddy. Thanks much :) Have no concerns over security or being hijacked 'cause it's only me using it...

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the arguments passed to the `main()` function. Change the function's signature to:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Then loop over the string pointers in `argv[]`, which will be the command-line arguments your program was given.